# ACL package for Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, acl

I'am using Klaravel\Ntrust for ACL in my Laravel 5.3 application.I wish  to upgrade it to a Laravel 5.4 application. But Klaravel\Ntrust don't support Laravel 5.4

Also doesn't see any ACL Package for Laravel 5.4 .

```
Klaravel\Ntrust\NtrustServiceProvider::class,
'Ntrust' => Klaravel\Ntrust\NtrustFacade::class,
```

Comment: i didn't used that package before, but check the [changelog](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/releases) for the 5.4 version , and check any probably conflict between the package and the changes, if there are not then you may use it

Comment: @hassan yeah I already checked.it don't suppport

Answer (score 1):

I am using laratrust package and worked very well. I upgraded laravel 5.3 to 5.4 and it was working without breaking it.

[Check it out](https://github.com/santigarcor/laratrust).

Repository is active and support is fantastic.

Comment: Ok. I will try it

Comment: Check out Laratrust Package's documentation before trying it. :)